# Use tools to config eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Is there any tools to config eclipse auto?I have many eclipses need to be set some preferences like **Displayed tab width** and so on.

I try google and found nothing useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 'File > Export > General > Preferences' to export the Eclipse preferences to a file. There is a corresponding 'File > Import > General > Preferences' to import the saved preferences.

Some preferences such as the Java Formatter and Code Templates have their own Export options on their preference page.

Comment: Can I export all at once?

Comment: If you mean the Formatter and Code Template preferences, no these have to be done separately.

Answer (score 0):

There is **Formatter** in eclipse to format code.
Go to **Window --> Preferences --> Java --> Code Style --> Formatter**.
You can define your own rules to format code.

Comment: Yeah, but I have some IDE related preferences like **text file encoding**. Can I export these settings?